# How to automatically connect to WiFi as soon as it wakes up?

Tags: networking, ssh, suspend, 22.04

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 as a Server running NextCloud.

I've made adjustments using crontab to have it sleep and wake up at specified times. However, when the PC goes to sleep and wakes up, it has to wait for a user to actively log in before it connects to WiFi. In order for the Wi-Fi to reconnect, I have to log in either through ssh (as I usually do) or directly.

Is there a way of having this PC immediately connect to WiFi without user intervention?

Comment: Is your wifi connection set to "share with other users"?

Comment: Another thing you can do is sign into wifi on the login screen before you log in. You should be able to get to the wifi settings somewhere on the upper right hand side of the login screen.

Comment: Once either one of those methods is used, it should sign in to wifi automatically before a user is logged in.

Comment: Of course, you should also have it set to "automatically connect to this network when available".

Comment: It works now, thank you so much!